# Sikuli opening windows start menu without reason

Tags: sikuli

Im trying to create a script that works on two differents windows simultaneously, but everytime the script clicks, it opens the windows start menu without reason which hides part of my screen and cause FindFailed errors.

What can I do to prevent that ? What causes this issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clicks with SikuliX are not "simultaneously" but always sequentially one after the other.
So tell a bit more about your setup.
A relevant snippet of your script code might help as well.

Have you tried "run in slow motion", where you can better watch, where the mouse moves and clicks?

Comment: Sorry by "simultaneously" I meant on both windows appearing on screen at the same time. I tried to run the script in slow motion but everything seem to be working as it should, I don't see the reason why the start menu appears. Here's the part of the code that causes this problem :  `region1.click(Pattern("Image1.png").targetOffset(-4,17),20)
type("1" + "0")`

Comment: It seems like you click on some input field to activate it for the following type. Just put a wait(1) before the type. In many cases GUI elements need some time to get ready for the next user action (like typing something). So the type in your case goes to the desktop, I guess.